# Showing that we can't always align the decompositions of finitely generated modules over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am working on the following exercise.

> If $M$ is a finitely generated module over a PID $A$ and $M′$ is a
>   submodule, can we write $M = F ⊕ T$ and $M′ = F′ ⊕ T′$ such that $F$
>   and $F′$ are free, $T$ and $T′$ are torsion, and $F′ \subset F$ and
>   $T′ \subset T$?

Following a hint, I've assumed $A$ contains an irreducible $p$. I then showed $M′ = A(p, \bar{1})$ is a free submodule of $M = A ⊕ A/(p)$.

Now I should show that $M'$ cannot be contained in the free part of $M$, but it seems to me that $M'$ is indeed contained in the free part of $M$. I'm not seeing how to use that $p$ is irreducible.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you think the free part of $M$ is?

Comment: @EricWofsey The elements $(x, \bar{y})$ where $x$ is nonzero.

Comment: Well, perhaps a better question would be, what do you think the definition of "free part" is?

Comment: $\{ (x, \bar y) \mid x \ne 0 \}$ isn't a submodule (it doesn't even contain the zero element) so it can't be equal to $F$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes true. Is the free part of a module the same as the torsion free elements?

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought that the free part just means the torsion free part.

Comment: the free part in the decomposition of a finitely generated module $M$ over a PID is not unique so $F'\subset F$ doesn't hold for any chosen free part $F$.